# Substitute matlab for loop for function input arguments

Tags: matlab

Here is my question :

I have   A = 1xN matrix  and B = 6xN matrix
I also have a function F = @(x,y) ...

What I want to do is to loop over the values of A and B in a way that each time the input arguments for F will be :  A(1,i) and B(:,i)

Is there a way to that for all values without using a for loop in order to gain some time?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With newer versions of MATLAB loops aren't as costly as you may think. If your function `F` is something relatively simple that can be easily vectorized then you can usually get faster performance than using a for loop, but if `F` represents a rather complex operation there may actually be more work required in trying to get around using a for loop.

Without knowing what `F` actually does, it's difficult to give you a *specific* answer. However, in addition to [vectorizing your operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867901/introduction-to-vectorizing-in-matlab-any-good-tutorials/2867951#2867951), there are a few functions that can be used in place of for loops for certain situations. Some examples of these would be [ARRAYFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html), [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html), [STRUCTFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/structfun.html), and [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html).

As an example of how to use [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html), let's say that the operation `F` that you are performing involves multiplying each column of `B` by the value in the corresponding column of `A`. In other words, `C(:,i) = A(1,i).*B(:,i);` for all `i`. You could do this using [BSXFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) as follows:

```
C = bsxfun(@times,B,A);
```