# Matlab : create my own dct2

Tags: matlab

==Question solved==

This code will get you the dct2 output.

I am working to make improvement on my own codes

Thank you.

```
%Get the size of the input image
[m, n] = size(image);
output = zeros(m,n);

for u = 0:m-1
    for v = 0:n-1
        if u==0
            a=sqrt(1/8);
        else
            a=sqrt(2/8);
        end

        if v==0
            b=sqrt(1/8);
        else
            b=sqrt(2/8);
        end

        temp = 0;
        for x = 0:m-1
            for y = 0:n-1
                temp = (cos((((2*x)+1)*pi*u)/(2*m))*cos((((2*y)+1)*pi*v)/(2*n)));
            end
        end

        output(u+1,v+1) = a*b*temp;
    end
end
```

Comment: Seems like it is running in infinite loop. When I forced to stop the program, it stop at line 26.

Comment: What is line 26? Also, how large are m/n?

Comment: you don't have an infinite loop, just a very inefficient code. You are performing 16*16*16*16 = 65536 iterations. So it may take awhile. You can even track your progress but putting `disp(u)` in the first for loop and `disp(v)` in the second

Comment: The best solution is to be patient, if performance is an issue you will want to look at this for advice on vectorizing the code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867901/introduction-to-vectorizing-in-matlab-any-good-tutorials

Comment: I use this function (dctII) on a 8x8 matrix and use Matlab dct2 function on the same 8x8 matrix, but the outcome is so different. May I know any part of my code (dctII) did wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code if you are trying to compare it to the Matlab function `dct2`. For the record, you can open and analyze the files to understand what Matlab is doing.

In both case you are not following the formula:

1. a and b need to be a function of n:

   ```
   if u==0
       a=sqrt(1/n);
   else
       a=sqrt(2/n);
   end

   if v==0
       b=sqrt(1/n);
   else
       b=sqrt(2/n);
   end
   ```
2. You need to multiply your `temp` term by the image values (which you are not doing):

   ```
   temp = temp+(image(x+1,y+1))*(cos((((2*x)+1)*pi*u)/(2*m))*cos((((2*y)+1)*pi*v)/(2*n)));
   ```

I haven't addressed the performance problem, and you really should look into that on your own.

Comment: Rasman, thanks for your help. Now my function is the same as Matlab one. I just want to try out with my own code, so the performance problem can be neglected. Thanks again.